# Сохранение mysqldump удаленным php скриптом

Tags: php, shell

Ломаю голову как доработать shell-команду.
Текущая версия позволяет вывод mysqldump запаковывать в sql.gz и отправлять по ssh

`ssh <server1> "mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> <db> | gzip | ssh <server2> 'cat > /file/path/to/save/filename.sql.gz'"`

Как ее доработать что бы она отправляла не в `/file/path/to/save/filename.sql.gz`, а через http запрос в скрипт?

Comment: [похожий ворос на serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/313599/how-do-i-pipe-the-output-of-uptime-df-to-curl).

Comment: @Arnial спасибо за ответ, у меня проблема с тем что у меня файл, и не малого веса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение моего вопроса:
`ssh <server1> "mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> <db> | gzip | curl -X POST -F \"dump=@-\" http://domain/script.php"`